# Playframework : http.path is set, but can't locate to home page

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I've set the home path in application.conf:

`http.path=/vcloud/`

But now I can't access `http://localhost:9000/vcloud/`, I thought this path should direct to my home page, but now it's an 404 error page.

Here's my routes:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index

# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

I'm using Play 1.x

Comment: It should work. Did you restart your server after modify application.conf?

Answer (score 1):

if you drop the last slash it should work as expected.

```
http.path=/vcloud
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Play 2.0.x, it needs to be application.context as described here
[[2.0] is there an equivalent of http.path play 1.x setting?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/2722JpogWsY)